# Mysql - calculate difference between two columns in 2 different tables and insert 

Tags: mysql

I have the following statement which need to add 1 more subquery to calculate the difference between the number of followers in the `tweeps` table and the number in the current column in the `ranking` table and insert the difference in column called `latest` in `ranking` table sure PK is screenname ,

Like number in follower coulm in tweeps table is 10 current coulmn n ranking table for the same screenname is 5 the value will be added to latest is +5

```
mysql_query ("
    INSERT  INTO ranking
    SELECT @rank := @rank + 1, tweeps.* FROM tweeps
    JOIN( SELECT @rank := 0 ) AS init
    ORDER BY followers DESC
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    ranking.ranking = @rank, 
    ranking.name = tweeps.name,
    ranking.followers = tweeps.followers,
    ranking.tweets = tweeps.tweets,
    ranking.location = tweeps.location,
    ranking.`join date` = tweeps.join_date,
    ranking.avatar = tweeps.avatar;");
mysql_close($con);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO ranking
SELECT @rank := @rank + 1, tweeps.* FROM tweeps
JOIN( SELECT @rank := 0 ) AS init
ORDER BY followers DESC
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE ranking set
ranking = @rank, 
name = tweeps.name,
followers = tweeps.followers - followers,
tweets = tweeps.tweets,
location = tweeps.location,
`join date` = tweeps.join_date,
avatar = tweeps.avatar;
```

I changed the syntax to `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ranking set...`

Comment: thanks for adjust code , but still have nothing to do with  calculate the difference between the number of followers

Comment: huh? did you notice the other change: `followers = tweeps.followers - followers` ?